# <urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read csv file from website. The link exists, but it raises an error

My code is:

```
pd.read_csv("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.csv")
```

and an error is:

`<urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>` .

UPDATE: I tried another link, with smaller dataset, and it executes with no problem. I guess, maybe wrong, error is raised due to bigger dataset.

So how to deal with the link above then?

Comment: Have you tried using `requests` and getting the content of the file first before reading as a dataframe? `import requests; from io import StringIO; import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv(StringIO(requests.get("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.csv").content.decode('utf8')))`. Does that work?

Comment: @Abdou I tried the code now, and this time it says `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3189). It may be helpful to you.

Comment: I followed some steps in the link you provided, and re-executed the code you mentioned above and it works now. However, the issue of error still there.

Comment: What issue of error are you referring to?

Comment: the error when I try to read csv file from the link: `<urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me; it might be caused by your general network settings.

Comment: yes it does of course. it doesn't work for me, it raises an error. I'm just  looking for help to solve this issue.